# Jump to Vimscript breakpoint

Tags: vimscript

Do you know how to jump to a defined Vimscript breakpoint ?

For example I define a breakpoint with:

```
:breakadd
```

Then I can see it with:

```
:breaklist
> 1  func <SNR>114_MyFunctionName  line 2
```

And I didn't found any way to jump to the breakpoint defined.
Do you know if there is such option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there isn't. Sometimes jumping to a breapoint can make no sense - e.g. when you add a breakpoint for a function which is not yet defined.

You can use the normal  jumping mechanisms instead - for example, based on ctags.